# Добавление данных формулой SQL

Tags: sql, база-данных, запрос

я бы хотел узнать, как, если это возможно, я могу при помощи формулы заполнять ячейки в SQL таблице, как в Excel, чтобы данные брались из других ячеек, как-то вычислялись формулой и в пустую ячейку уже по формуле добавлялось новое значение
Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: В пределах одной записи - generated column. Шире - view.

Comment: Для чего именно это вам понадобилось, опишите конечную цель более полно. Тогда можно будет выбрать тот способ, который вам больше подойдет. И укажите какая именно база данных используется, у разных баз разные возможности

Comment: У меня есть файл Excel в котором есть данные вводимые вручную, а также данные которые вычисляются формулами, я хочу переделать это все в виде БД, использую MySQL